# Example Code of CasperJS is Not Working

Tags: javascript, casperjs

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var links;

function getLinks() {
// Scrape the links from top-right nav of the website
var links = document.querySelectorAll('ul.navigation li a');
return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (e) {
    return e.getAttribute('href')
});
}

// Opens casperjs homepage
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/');

casper.then(function () {
links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.run(function () {
for(var i in links) {
    console.log(links[i]);
}
casper.done();
});
```

I received an error related to `casper.start()`, so I tested the source code anticipating that it would properly work if my computer did not have something different from other normal computers posted in http://casperjs.org/.

But I received the error message: `casper.start() is not function`.

I heard if I run **selftest.js** in CasperJS, I can see what the problem is.

So I ran it, and the result was: `ReferenceError: patchRequire is not defined`.

I think something is wrong with the CasperJS file.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your program, and I also received an error.

After making the proper revisions, the following code worked as expected:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks () {
  // Scrape the links from top-right nav of the website
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('ul.navigation li a');

  return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (e) {
    return e.getAttribute('href');
  });
}

// Opens CasperJS homepage
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/');

casper.then(function () {
  var links = this.evaluate(getLinks);

  for (var i in links) {
    this.echo(links[i]);
  }
});

casper.run();
```

If you are still receiving errors after making these changes, I would recommend reinstalling CasperJS (and possibly PhantomJS as well) using the [Official Installation Guide](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html).